# Push a message in a nested array (Mongodb)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to push a message object into the messages array and update people with the newly pushed message.

pushing message to the friend field works when consoling. but people is not updated with the pushed message.

All the other fetching as well as pushing new friends into the friends array and updating the friends array is working properly. My problem is when trying to push new message to the messages array.
Any help please?

here is my model

`````
people: [
  {
    _id: xxxxxxxxx,
    name: abc,
    email: abc@gmail.com,
    friends: [
      {
        _id: yyyyyyy,
        name: name,
        email: bcd@yahoo.com,
        messages: [
          {
            message: 'Hello world',
            timestamp: 1234,
            sender: abc@yahoo.com
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]

Here is my patch

app.patch('/chat/setMessages/:ids', async (req, res) =>{
    const id = req.params.ids.split(','); //id is an array of two ids id[0] is person id and id[1] friend id 
    
    const person = await People.findById(id[0])
    const friends = person.friends
    friends.forEach(friend => {
        if (id[1].toString() === friend._id.toString()) {
            friend.messages.push(req.body)
        }
    }) //until this is working fine, consoling friend shows the message is pushed in it. but the people is not updated with the pushed message. Any help please? 
    
    const updatedPeople = People.findByIdAndUpdate(id[0], person, { new: true })
    
})

Sorry! here is my schema. The schema is working fine when fetching the data, as well as populating some higher level fields.````

import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const peopleSchema = new Schema({
    _id: String,
    name: String,
    imageUrl: String,
    email: String,
    loginStatus: String,
    registeredOn: String,
    friends: [
        {
            name: String,
            imageUrl: String,
            email: String,
            dateAdded: String,
            loginStatus: String,
            messages : [
                        {
                            message: String,
                            email: String,
                            name: String,
                            image: String,
                            timestamp: String,
                        }
                    ]  
            }
    ]
})
const People = mongoose.model('people', peopleSchema);

export default People;
`````

Comment: Can you upload your schema for `People`?

Comment: thank you cseitz. I have uploaded the schema now.

Comment: Never mind I have fixed it. If any one want the solution, it is as follows: app.patch('/chat/setMessages/:ids', async (req, res) =>{
    const id = req.params.ids.split(',');                  await People.updateOne({_id: id[0]},              {$push: {'friends.$[f].messages' : req.body }},                    {arrayFilters: [{'f._id' : id[1]}]})                                                   });